# React native transform background

Tags: react-native

I would like to ask if how can I copy this image using the transform styles in react native. SO far here's my code and didn't exactly the same with the image:

**This is want to copy:**

[image]

**Here's what I got:**

```
backgroundColor: STATUS_BAR_COLOR,
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    transform: [
      { skewY: '-30deg' },
    ],
    height: 150
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a perfect answer, but this link will help you. Combining the codes for the shapes given in the link, you can make most kinds of geometric shapes you need. Good luck.
http://browniefed.com/blog/the-shapes-of-react-native/